# matplotlibs ginput() with undefined number of points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to define an area in a plot(s) using the matplotlib function ginput(). However since it is an irregular shape and will be different in each plot so I cant define how many points there will be before hand, i.e.

```
x = randn(10,10)
imshow(x)
n = I don't know yet
points = ginput(n)
```

Anyone know how to go about this??
thanks
Dave

Comment: I dont think you can do this as it has no way of knowing when to stop... try using TK or wx or pygame or some other framework that listens for mouse clicks and record the coordinates and then when condition to stop is met use a different method to plot it... or plot after every click

Comment: What defines the number of points?

Comment: x = randn(10,10)
imshow(x)

button = False
points = []
while button == False:
    points.append(ginput(1))
    button = waitforbuttonpress()

Comment: The above almost does what I need but needs a double click to define a point which I would like to avoid. @ms4py I need to define an area around a local maximum in a pcolor plot keeping as close as possible to the edges, this is different in each plot and always has an irregular shape so there is no way to predict how many points will be needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs, i.e. `help(ginput)`,

> ginput(self, n=1, timeout=30, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=1, mouse_pop=3, mouse_stop=2)
>
> Blocking call to interact with the figure.
>
> This will wait for *n* clicks from the user and return a list of the
>   coordinates of each click.
>
> If *timeout* is zero or negative, does not timeout.
>
> If *n* is zero or negative, accumulate clicks until a middle click
>   (or potentially both mouse buttons at once) terminates the input.
>
> Right clicking cancels last input.
>
> The buttons used for the various actions (adding points, removing
>   points, terminating the inputs) can be overriden via the
>   arguments *mouse_add*, *mouse_pop* and *mouse_stop*, that give
>   the associated mouse button: 1 for left, 2 for middle, 3 for
>   right.
>
> The keyboard can also be used to select points in case your mouse
>   does not have one or more of the buttons.  The delete and backspace
>   keys act like right clicking (i.e., remove last point), the enter key
>   terminates input and any other key (not already used by the window
>   manager) selects a point.

We can **set `n=0`** to have ginput wait for a mouse middle click instead of a set number of points.

Bonus: setting `timeout=0` stops ginput from quitting after the default 30s. I find this annoying for complex plots.

Example code:

```
import pylab
x = randn(10,10)
imshow(x)
points = ginput(0, 0)
# Select the points defining your region from the
# plot then middle click to terminate ginput.
```